# "Original error: Neither ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable was exported." Even when already set in ~/.zprofile

Tags: android

`"Original error: Neither ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable was exported." Even when already set in ~/.zshrc   and .bash_profile and .bashrc kindly suggest.[debug] [HTTP] Request idempotency key: fa345fcd-cf62-4ca6-acae-99beba29c099

[HTTP] --> POST /session

[HTTP] {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{}],"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app":"/Users/e007150/eclipse-workspace/test/src/test/resources/app

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.